# How to handle compile errors thrown from M5Stack libraries in Arduino

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, shared-libraries

I'm currently trying to program my M5Stack with an ESP32 chip in it. I downloaded (or atleast I thought) all of the dependencies needed to upload to the board, but I can't even get my program to compile. I downloaded the ESP32 throught the board manager, I followed the M5Stack tutorial on their website and seem to be finding errors in thheir library itself. I'm not sure how to fix, below is my code and below that are the error messages im getting.

```
#include <M5Stack.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#define SPEAKER_PIN 25
#include "config.h"

AdafruitIO_Feed *voltage1 = io.feed("V1");
AdafruitIO_Feed *voltage2 = io.feed("V2");
AdafruitIO_Feed *curr = io.feed("Current");

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  M5.begin(true, true, true, false);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dacWrite(25,0);
  M5.Lcd.fillScreen(BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.setTextSize(5);

  // wait for serial monitor to open
  while(! Serial);

  Serial.print("Connecting to Adafruit IO");

  // connect to io.adafruit.com
  io.connect();

  // wait for a connection
  while(io.status() < AIO_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  // we are connected
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(io.statusText());


//  ads.getAddr_ADS1100(ADS1100_DEFAULT_ADDRESS);
//  ads.setGain(GAIN_ONE);
//  ads.setMode(MODE_CONTIN);
//  ads.setRate(RATE_32);
//  ads.setOSMode(OSMODE_SINGLE);
//  ads.begin();
}

void loop() {

  io.run();

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  float v1 = (float)analogRead(36) / 4096 * 17.4  * 0.975;
  float v2 = (float)analogRead(35) / 4096 * 17.4 * 0.975;
  float current = (float)analogRead(5);


  Serial.print("v1: ");
  Serial.print(v1);
  Serial.println("V");
  Serial.print("v2: ");
  Serial.print(v2);
  Serial.println("V");

  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(WHITE);
  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 10);
  M5.Lcd.print("V1: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(v1);
  M5.Lcd.print("V");

  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(WHITE);
  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 70);
  M5.Lcd.print("V2: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(v2);
  M5.Lcd.print("V");

  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(WHITE);
  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 140);
  M5.Lcd.print("Current: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(current);
  M5.Lcd.print("A");
  delay(500);

  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 10);
  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.print("V1: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(v1);
  M5.Lcd.print("V");

  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 70);
  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.print("V2: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(v2);
  M5.Lcd.print("V");

  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 140);
  M5.Lcd.print("Current: ");
  M5.Lcd.print(current);
  M5.Lcd.print("A");


  Serial.print("sending v1-> ");
  Serial.println(v1);
  voltage1->save(v1);

  Serial.print("sending v2-> "); 
  Serial.println(v2);
  voltage2->save(v2);

  Serial.print("sending Current-> ");
  Serial.println(current);
  curr->save(current);

}
```

Error output:

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "M5Stack-Core-ESP32, QIO, 80MHz, Default, 921600, None"

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp: In member function 'void M5Display::drawPngUrl(const char*, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, double, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:543:3: error: 'HTTPClient' was not declared in this scope
   HTTPClient http;
   ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:545:7: error: 'WiFi' was not declared in this scope
   if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
       ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:545:24: error: 'WL_CONNECTED' was not declared in this scope
   if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
                        ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:550:3: error: 'http' was not declared in this scope
   http.begin(url);
   ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:553:19: error: 'HTTP_CODE_OK' was not declared in this scope
   if (httpCode != HTTP_CODE_OK) {
                   ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:559:3: error: 'WiFiClient' was not declared in this scope
   WiFiClient *stream = http.getStreamPtr();
   ^

C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\M5Stack\src\M5Display.cpp:559:15: error: 'stream' was not declared in this scope
   WiFiClient *stream = http.getStreamPtr();
               ^

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: C:\Users\graff\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"
 Used: C:\Users\graff\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\SD
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD
 Not used: C:\Users\graff\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SD
exit status 1
Error compiling for board M5Stack-Core-ESP32.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should do what your compiler wants:

```
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

This gives more details and if the solution is not working edit your question and replace the compiler output with the detailed Info.Include the missinglibs manually in your program

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <M5Stack.h>
#include <Wire.h>
```

and checkthe dependencies you have in

```
#include "config.h"
```

as I could not compile due to missing file